# Google Apps Script - Send Email based on date in cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've looked around and have bits and pieces but can't put the puzzle together.  I'm attempting to create a script that will run on a trigger configured to run daily.  The trigger will be setup under Resources option in the editor.

Basically I'm looking for the script to capture a range of cells, identify a due date, which will be populated in a column, match it to the current date.  If it matches then send a email.  I've started with the send a email from spreadsheet tutorial at Google.  I've added in a if statement to check for the date but I'm losing it on the comparsion to dataRange.  Anyone might help correct these or point me to in direction to research.

The script appears to run but nothing happens, which I believe is because "if (currentTime == dataRange)"  The dataRange is not matching correctly??

Here is the code:

```
function sendEmails() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 50;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2)
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();   
//Get todays date     
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var day = currentTime.getDate();
var year = currentTime.getFullYear();      
//Test column  for date due & match to current date
    if ( currentTime == dataRange) {
  for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
var message = row[1];       // Second column
var subject = "Task Item Due";
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
}
}
```

I'm updating the suggestion provided by Srik and providing his  suggestion in the below code.  I've attempted to post this a couple time so I'm not sure why its not making past peer review?

```
 function sendEmail() {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = 50;   // Number of rows to process

var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 50);

// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Browser.msgBox(data)

for (i in data) {
var row = data[i];
var date = new Date();
var sheetDate = new Date(row[1]);

if (date.getDate() == sheetDate.getDate() && date.getMonth() == sheetDate.getMonth() && date.getFullYear() == sheetDate.getFullYear());
{
  var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
  var message = row[2];       // Second column
  var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
 // Browser.msgBox(emailAddress)

}

}

}
```

The code appears to run but I'm getting the following error w/in the script editor.  "Failed to send email: no recipient (line 23)".  But it still sends emails.  It should compare the dates and only send the email if the date matches.  Its sending an email for every row.  I've shared out the spreadsheet to see the code and how the spreadsheet is setup.  [Shared Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AiB8MImvI1UMdGx0WTRsUmVHSjl1dVNPTkxtWlNmcGc)

UPDATED CODE W/ SERGE HELP on the logger and Utilities.formatDate..  Thanks!!

```
function sendEmail() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
// Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
// Fetch values for each row in the Range.
var data = dataRange.getValues();
//Logger.log(data)

for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0);
  date.setMinutes(0);
  date.setSeconds(0);
  //Logger.log(date);
  var sheetDate = new Date(row[2]);
 //Logger.log(sheetDate);
 var Sdate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd')
 var SsheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0200', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
     Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
        if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
          var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
          var message = row[1];       // Second column
          var subject = "Your assigned task is due today." +message;
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
          //Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
            }    
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is a working version of your code, I used Utilities.formatDate to make strings of your dates, so you can choose what you compare (only days, hours ? min ?)

I commented the mail call just for my tests, re-enable it when you need

```
function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row[1]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT+0200','yyyy:MM:dd')
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT+0200', 'yyyy:MM:dd')
    Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[2];       // Second column
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
//      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
     Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
    }    
  }
}
```

don't forget to look at the logs ;-)

Comment: Ok.. Ok.. Looks like progress is being made.. Thanks for using the logger.. if you noticed Browswer.msgBox comments I was trying to debug a bit myself. but the logging is much better.  So it looks like the current date is showing a day ahead of time.  6/17/2012??  As it outputs this to the logs 2012:06:17 =? 2012:06:15    Not really sure why it would pull a date for tomorrow and not the actual day..  gonna start digging and will update as I uncover :)

Comment: Got it working, not sure its the best or the smartest way.  I used the .setHours, .setMinutes, and setSeconds on the current date, which now matches the dates pulled from the spreadsheet.   Emails flow just right :)  Thanks Serge for helping me out on that.    If anyone thinks my addition of the .setHOurs etc methods please let me know.    Javascript is new to me so I'm trying to soak up what I can..  Thanks again..

Comment: The issue you had is probably related to timezone, I used GMT+0200 wich is right for me but probably not for you ;-)  check also the settings in your spreadsheet. (check the old forum for info about dates in GAS)

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way ....

Setup the spreadsheet like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkGlO9jJLGO8dDJad3VNTkhJcHR3UXlJSVRNTFJreWc

Change the code to:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('Type spreadsheet key here from spreadsheet URL');       
  /// e.g.  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AkGlO9jJLGO8dDJad3VNTkhJcHR3UXlJSVRNTFJreWc');     

  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]; // gets the first sheet, i.e. sheet 0

  var range = sheet.getRange("B1"); 
  var dateString = new Date().toString();
  range.setValue(dateString);   // this makes all formulas recalculate

  var startRow = 4;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 50;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();   

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    if( row[3] == true) {
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var message = row[1];       // Second column
      var subject = "Task Item Due";
      try {
          MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      } catch(errorDetails) {
        // MailApp.sendEmail("eddyparkinson@someaddress.com", "sendEmail script error", errorDetails.message);
      }

    }
  }
}
```

The trigger:

Because of the trigger, you will need to open the spreadsheet using openById.
 To do this, in the code replace 'Type spreadsheet key here from spreadsheet URL'.
 To find the key, open the google docs spreadsheet, the link has "key=A0a0df..." paste the code. See the example.

JavaScript:
 if you want to learn more about using Java Script, I recommend http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to w3schools.. I've actually looked over that site for references etc..  I'm actually signed up at lynda.com to help as well as leverage several books.  I'm just venturing into JavaScript and more so Google Apps Script as my company is a Google Apps company.   I've kind leaned towards Srik option below as I think it more fits my needs..  Basically have a project planning spreadsheet that has columns of info.. IE Task column, Assigned to, email, due date  The script should run and identify the due date, match to current date and send email notification if matching.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two different objects here

```
    if ( currentTime == dataRange) {
```

currentTime is a Date object whereas dataRange is a Range object - they'll never be equal and so nothing happens.
What you could do is (DATE_COL is the column having your date)

```
for ( var i in data ){
  var row = data[i] ; 
  var today = new Date(); 
  var date = new Date(row[DATE_COL]) ; 

  if (today.getDate() == date.getDate() && 
      today.getMonth() == date.getMonth() && 
      today.getYear() == date.getYear() {
    /* Your email code here */ 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.. I'm currently working to test it out, not all they way there but I think I'm getting close.  One question I do have, since I'm new to JavaScript / GAS is fully understanding the "for (var i in data)".  I see that you've added it this way and above from the GAS tutorial its noted "for (i in data)".  Can anyone help me understand this and what "i" means?

Comment: Is "i" a variable that gets a value based on the array in the variable data?

Comment: Here is the updated code adding in the feedback from Srik.. Still not able to get it to recognize and fire off an email.  I have a Google spreadsheet with three columns A, B, C.  a = email, b = task, c = data due.  script should capture the range starting at a2:c6 (have 6 lines filled in) see if dates entered in column C match the current date, if so send email.  Is the date format off cause it not to match?

Comment: Srik,  I keep editing your post to add the updated code some I'm not sure why its not making it past peer review?  I'm new here so not sure if I'm just missing something.  I can post it in another answer reply?

Comment: Ok.. reading back over the FAQ I figured out where I was going wrong w/ editing of post.. sorry guys..  my post should be updated to see the new updated code w/ your suggestion