# Send a mail to guest of an event

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to send a evaluation to a meeting guest at the end of the meeting.

I am trying to extract real participants (ones who answer yes to the invitation) using getGuestStatus()

```
for (var j=0; j<listeParticipants.length;j++) {
  var assiste = listeParticipants[j].getGuestStatus();
  if ( assiste = "YES"){ 
    mailsParti = mailsParti.concat(listeParticipants[j].getEmail()+";");
  }
```

I don't understand why "assiste" variable stays with the value "YES" even when getGuestStatus return "NO"

As a result all participants are added to mailsParti string.

Thank you for helping (I really feel I'am missing something simple)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and enough code for a [mcve]

Comment: [Here's an example of a sendMail script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109608/7215091).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if ( assiste = "YES")` = is an assigment. == is a comparison.

#### [Reference link](http://wiki.c2.com/?AssignmentVsEqualityOperator)

Comment: Thank you very much