# Apps script: Send html emails based on dates specified in different columns

Tags: google-apps-script

This issue has been discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33499410/send-reminder-emails-based-on-date) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743434/google-apps-script-send-email-based-on-data-in-cell). But none of the scripts I´ve seen and analyzed with a great deal of attention seems to solve my problem. That´s why I am calling on all brilliant minds out there to help me.

Here are the details of my problem:

**ISSUE:** 
My current script (see it below) sends out an **html email** to each recipient listed in my sheet and then set the status for each recipient receiving that html email to “EMAIL SENT” in column K. Now I want to send 3 additional html emails to each of these recipients exactly on the dates that I´ve already specified in column L, M and N for each recipient.

***Example***: recipient A received the first html email on 11.10.2021 (format used: **day/month/year**) and he is scheduled to receive the second html email on 25.10.2021, the third html email on 27.10.2021 and the forth/last html email on 29.10.2021. These dates for recipient A are specified in column L (25.10.2021), column M (27.10.2021) and column N (29.10.2021).

**QUESTION:**
How can I ensure that each recipient receives the additional emails on the dates specified for him in column L, M and N?

I´d really appreciate any help or hint to solve this problem.

Here is my current script:

```
function sendEmail() {
  // variables for the html template (html file) and the list of recipients (google sheet)
  const anrede = 2;
  const nachname = 3;
  const emailAdresse = 5;
  const terminTag = 6;
  const terminUhrzeit = 8;
  const terminURL = 9;
  let emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('HTML_TEMPLATE');
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("LIST_OF_RECIPIENTS");

  // send email based on my html template and recipients list
  var adminV = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("admin"); // open the sheet containing the subject of the email ("subject in German is "betreff")
  var betreff = adminV.getRange("A20").getValue(); // get the actual content of the sheet containing the subject ("subject in German is "betreff")
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases(); // get the alises of my gmail-account
  const sr = 3;//start row of data/recipients list from the google sheet
  const data = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 11).getValues();
  data.forEach((row, i) => {
    if (row[10] == "EMAIL NOT SENT YET") {
      emailTemp.anrede1 = (row[anrede]);
      emailTemp.nachname1 = (row[nachname]);
      emailTemp.emailAdresse1 = (row[emailAdresse]);
      emailTemp.terminTag1 = (row[terminTag]);
      emailTemp.terminUhrzeit1 = (row[terminUhrzeit]);
      emailTemp.terminURL1 = (row[terminURL]);
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(row[emailAdresse],
        betreff, "This is an html email. Please change your seting to be able to read it.",
        { from: aliases[0], htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: aliases[0] });
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 11).setValue("EMAIL SENT");//stops emails this particular email from being sent again, if the recipient has already received it.
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: @Kos: Unfortunately not. And here is why: as explained in my initial question, the script you suggested considers just 1 column with reminder dates. But I have 3 columns with reminder dates. So, I need a script that can trigger my sendEmail() function, as soon as the reminder date is one of the dates specified in one of the 3 columns (L, M or N). Does it make sense?

Comment: @Kos: By the way, I am pretty new at using Apps Script. So, please forgive me, if I am messing up something here. Thanks :)

Comment: But you not just looking for free code right? So you can check linked answer and understand how it works, and then apply to 3 or 4 or 999 columns. If it's too hard, then hire someone to do this job for you

Comment: @Kos - Not looking for free code. Just trying to figure out how to do it by myself and asking around at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send the emails for dates which are in the future, the best solution would be to use a time-based trigger. In this way, your function `sendEmail` will end up running every day and by checking the current date with the dates in `L`, `M`, `N` columns the email will be sent accordingly.

```
function sendEmail() {
   let today = new Date();
   let todayDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, "GMT", "dd.mm.yyyy").toString();
   // the rest of the code
   // add the rest of it in the for loop
   data.forEach((row, i) => {
      let lCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 12).getValue();
      let mCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 13).getValue();
      let nCell = sh.getRange(i + 1, 14).getValue();
      if (lCell == todayDate || mCell == todayDate || nCell == todayDate) {
      // send email
      }
   }
}
```

```
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .everyDays(1)
      .create();
}
```

As for the `createTimeDrivenTrigger` function, this is the function that will create the trigger for the `sendEmail` function and by using `everyDays(1)` you are ensuring that this will end up running every day.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Manage Triggers Programmatically](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically).

Comment: I just adapted your code to mine, and it´s working like magic. Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: By the way, if you allow me this little remark: there was a bracket missing at the end (so, before the final curly bracket) in your modified sendEmail function. Thank you so much again :)

Comment: Sorry about that! I had just added it :)

Comment: Sure :). Thanks a lot :).